# Rails, what is a proper way to include callbacks into tableless model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm extending and including those files but still receive: `undefined method after_initialize for Play:Class`

```
class Play
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  after_initialize :process_data
  #...
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: Seems like the class you want is part of ActiveRecord, not ActiveModel? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try out following code

```
class Play
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :initialize, :only => :after

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end

    run_callbacks :initialize do
      puts 'initialize callback'
    end
  end

  def attributes
    return @attributes if @attributes
    @attributes = {
      'name' => name
    }
  end
end

#1.9.2-p290 :001 > Play.new(:name => 'The name')
#initialize callback
# => #<Play:0x00000006806050 @name="The name"> 
#1.9.2-p290 :002 >
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you need all the ActiveModel overhead, but you could do it with less code:

```
class Play
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def initialize(attributes)
    super(attributes)
    after_initialize
  end

  private

  def after_initialize
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: What `default_player_options` would be in this case? A hash with the default attributes?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, that shouldnt have been there. That would be if you wanted to have default options in a class method.

Comment: Is this fully replaces `initialize` method? Not sure about.

Comment: @hlcs It replaces it, but still calls the original with "super"

Comment: Nice simple solution. I changed the signature to `def initialize(attributes = {})` in case there are no attribute params.